# AWS Cloudwatch Logs Filter out Chrome User Agent to Show Safari

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I'm trying to filter out Chrome User Agent in Cloudwatch logs so that I can view the Safari User Agents on their own. I've added a regex to look ahead and ignore the ending if it contains Chrome.... then Safari... and only show the user agents that end with Safari... I've tested this in a regex builder but in AWS it doesn't show any results.

| parse @message /'User-Agent': '((?!.+Chrome/[\d+.+\d+]+ Safari/[\d+.+\d+]+) .+Safari/(?<Version_Number>[\d+.+\d+]+))'$/

Any help would be appreciated here.

Comment: What are you using – the console? What entity are producing those logs?

Comment: This is in the Cloudwatch Dashboard widget. I'm using a query to produce a list of the different Chrome versions being used to access our website. The logs are being produced from a lambda.